# NETLOGO I am asked for a "literal value" for a global variable inserted with slider in the interface

Tags: netlogo

I would like to write this addition in "to go":

```
 ask population with [employed = false and color = grey] [
set moneyOnBankOfGrey sum [ moneyOnBankOfGrey - min-indiv-cost-of-living]
```

]

but it gives me an error for the "moneyOnBankOfGrey" inside the brackets, it asks to insert a literal value.
but I entered moneyOnBankofGrey as a global variable in the interface with a slider.

I would also like to know how I could make this calculation occur every ticks. thank you very much! :)

Comment: if `moneyOnBankOfGrey` and `min-indiv-cost-of-living` are variables with a value, why do you have `sum [ ]` as well? Or are these variables owned by turtles or patches?

Comment: thanks for the reply.
 min-indiv-cost-of-living is a variable of the turtles (breed population); also moneyOnBankOfGrey should have been a variable of the population but I assigned it to the globals to be able to change its values from the interface. even removing the "sum" gives an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `moneyOnBankOfGrey` is a turtle variable, then this is probably what you want:

```
set moneyOnBankOfGrey sum [ moneyOnBankOfGrey - min-indiv-cost-of-living ] of turtles
```

so each turtle calculates the difference between its variable value and the global variable, then all those differences are added together